# Unable To Connect Python Sockets On Different Computers

Tags: python, sockets

I recently wrote a code for a small chat program in Python. Sockets connect fine when I connect them from different terminals on the same system. But the same doesn't seem to happen when I connect them from different computers which are connected over the same Wifi network.

Here's the server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "-"*60
print "WELCOME TO DYNASOCKET"
print "-"*60

import socket, os, sys, select

host = "192.168.1.101"
port = 8888
connlist = []

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Socket Successfully Created."
    connlist.append(s)
    s.bind((host,port))
    print "Socket Successfully Binded."
    s.listen(10)
    print "Socket is Now Listening."
except Exception, e:
    print "Error : " + str(e)
    sys.exit()

def air(sock,message):
    for socket in connlist:
        if socket != sock and socket != s:
            try:
                socket.sendall(message)
            except:
                connlist.remove(socket)

while 1:
    read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(connlist,[],[])
    for sock in read_sockets:
        if sock == s:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            connlist.append(conn)
            print "Connected With " + addr[0] + " : " + str(addr[1])
        else:
            try:
                key = conn.recv(1024)
                print "<" + str(addr[1]) + ">" + key
                data = raw_input("Server : ")
                conn.sendall(data + "\n")
                air(sock, "<" + str(sock.getpeername()) + ">" + key)

            except:
                connlist.remove(sock)
                print "Connection Lost With : " + str(addr[1])
conn.close()
s.close()
```

Here's the client script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "-"*60
print "WELCOME TO DYNASOCKET"
print "-"*60

import socket, os, sys

host = "192.168.1.101"
port = 8888

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Socket Successfully Created."
    s.connect((host,port))
    print "Connected With " + host + " : " + str(port)
except socket.error, e:
    print "Error : " + str(e)

while 1:
    reply = raw_input("Client : ")
    s.send(reply)
    message = s.recv(1024)
    print "Server : " + message

s.close()
```

When I try to connect The client From a different computer I get this error :

```
 Error : [Errno 10060] A Connection attempt failed because the connected party
 did not respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
 because connected host has failed to respnd.
```

Comment: Not really specific to python. Are you sure you don't have firewall blocking the traffic ?

Comment: Oftentimes problems like this arise because the router is not routing certain (most) ports like you'd expect it to. If you set the port number to 80 (the HTTP port) and try it again, does it still fail? I also assume you're running the server on the "host" computer specified there and not trying to connect the client to the wrong address.

Comment: I Don't Think the firewall is blocking any traffic. Also I tried changing the port to 80. But it still displays the same error. :(

Comment: Port 80 is a privileged port. Your OS will definitely block binding to port 80 for anyone other than the root user by default. If you're running the server script as a normal user then you have a problem if you're not seeing error messages.

Comment: So What Am I Supposed To Do...? Please Help !

Comment: Partition the problem: Is it your code or your configuration? To answer that, try running your server code on one machine and this command: `telnet 192.168.1.101 8888` on another. If this succeeds, then suspect your client code. If this fails, then suspect your router and/or server configuration. Better, if you have netcat, try: `nc -l 8888` on one machine and `nc 192.168.1.101 8888` on the other. If *that* fails, suspect your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your are binding your server only to the local host, so that connections from other hosts are blocked.

Try:

```
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",port))
```

Comment: Changed the host to "0.0.0.0". But still displays the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem and it took me a many hours to figure this out and I found that (like many others said @Cld) it is your firewall blocking the connection. How I fixed this:

1. Try to run the server onto the machine that you trying to connect from.
   (For example, if you want to run the server on machine A and connect from machine B, run the server on machine B).
2. If you are on windows (I am not sure about Mac or Linux) it will popup with with the firewall pop-up, which will allow you to give permission to your program to access your private network.
3. Simply tick the box that says:
   "Private networks, such as my home or work network"
   and Press allow access
4. That's it! You've fixed that particular issue. Now feel free to test the server on that machine or close the server and go back to your main machine, which will host that server and run it. You should see that it is now working.

I hope this has helped you, as it is my first post!

EDIT: I also did what @Daniel did in his post with changing the s.bind to include '0.0.0.0'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for quite sometime, and creating tcp tunnels with ngrok worked for me. You can check it out [here](https://ngrok.com/)

For simple sockets application on your pc, just expose the port you're using by `ngrok tcp <port_number>`, bind the server socket to localhost and port exposed, and use the url of the tunnel with the port number at client side (typically looks like `0.tcp.us.ngrok.io` and a port number).

You can even make multiple tunnels on the free account (needed in my case) by specifying the `--region` flag: https://ngrok.com/docs#global-locations