# Socket works when both scripts are on the same machine but not on separate

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make it so it send a video stream in between two computers.
My code seems to work locally but not on separate machines?
I don't know why it is not working could is be that I am sending data from server side?

I tried this but I dint seem to help:
[Unable To Connect Python Sockets On Different Computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584485/unable-to-connect-python-sockets-on-different-computers)

**SERVER CODE:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct
import os

hostname = socket.gethostname()
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

PORT = 8089

while True:
    try:
        while True:

            os.system('cls')
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print('Socket created')
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            print('Socket bind complete')
            s.listen(10)
            print('Socket now listening')
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print("Connected")

            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

            while True:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                # Serialize frame
                data = pickle.dumps(frame)

                # Send message length first
                message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data))  ### CHANGED

                # Then data
                conn.sendall(message_size + data)
    except:
        print("RESETING CONNECTION")
```

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct

import cv2

host = input("ROBOT IP:")

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect((host, 8089))

data = b'' ### CHANGED
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") ### CHANGED

while True:

    # Retrieve message size
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += clientsocket.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0] ### CHANGED

    # Retrieve all data based on message size
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += clientsocket.recv(4096)

    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    # Extract frame
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

    # Display
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Please Help

Comment: What means "not working"? What happens, what should happen (edit the question to explain and show error messages if present)?

Comment: Have you printed the `HOST` value to make sure you're not accidentally getting the loopback address, 127.0.0.1?  You might just want to bind to `0.0.0.0` so you get all the interfaces.

Comment: Are both of these machines within your network?  Can you ping the server from your local machine?

Comment: @TimRoberts It Responds with a 192.168 number and I thought binding to 0.0.0.0 would be like localhost? Both machines are on the same network.

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 is localhost.  "0.0.0.0" says "I want to listen on ALL interfaces."

Comment: @TimRoberts tried it it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

is producing the correct IP address for your device. I would suggest you print out what the HOST address is and make sure it corresponds to the IP address of your actual wlan or eth0 port IP address.

You can check your device IP address in many ways and it varies if you use Linux or Windows. Usually, it the command is ifconfig or ipconfig.

I had to do the same thing. My solution was to set my devices IP address as static and just hard-code the IP address into the code. But my circumstances may be different than yours.

Comment: It gives the correct IP a 192.168 number.

Comment: Did you start the server code before the client code?

Comment: I did start the Server before the client

Comment: What kind of network are you trying this on? Is this an apartment where you internet is shared? Or is this a school internet?

Comment: It is just a regular home internet with a static ip.

Comment: Did you check if port 8089 is being blocked on your router or device? You might have to enable it

Comment: I'm just sending the socket locally not over the internet. so I don't need to port forward yet.

Comment: Basically I want the server to transfer a webcam stream to the client.